# How replication works in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to hadoop , i am going through with the concept hdfs and replication 
 so i have a question related to that :

Suppose i am not changing  replication factor in hdfs-site.xml ,so i am keeping it   default  3 .
  what if  i create a cluster of 3 machines :
 1 master 
 2 slave

it means 2 data nodes would be there , since i am having replication factor  of 3 but  i have 2 data nodes to hold that data

how this scenarios work ?

would it create 3 copies or 2 copies ?
 would it create any problem ?
 would it show any warning ?

Answer (score 0):

It will create 2 copies. It will not create any problems but if you run a filesystem check (fsck) you will get a warning that some blocks are under replicated.